# Visual Studio 2008 - Where is the setting to switch on /off XML auto-comments?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, editor, xml-comments, setting

As the title says, my XML auto-comment feature (/// or ''') has stopped working!

Spent half an hour trying to find it in Tools/Options/Environment, Googled it, rebooted, etc still no luck :-(

Anyone knows where it is please?

Answer (score 0):

Print up the project properties and check the build tab.  On there you should see something about "XML documentation file".

Comment: Not asking about building the XML doc file, I am talkin about the feature in the editor where if you put your cursor above any function or sub and type (/// or ''' depending on C# or VB), the xml comments template gets inserted above the function.

Comment: Do you have resharper or anything else like it installed?  Some addons are really good at breaking the defaults in VS.